# How to wait for the download url in javascript firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

I have a map which will take an array of files and will return an array of download urls from firebase storage.

```
const imageUrls = images.map((image, index) => {
    const imageUploadTask = storage()
      .ref(`products/${dataUser.name}/${name}/${image.name}${index}`)
      .put(image);

    imageUploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {},
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        storage()
          .ref(`products/${dataUser.name}/${name}/${image.name}${index}`)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(url);
            return url;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    );
  });
```

When I log imageUrls array it returns an array of undefined. But in the console I see the urls logged after some time. It means urls are uploading but the code is not waiting for it and returns when the urls are not defined.

What am I doing wrong? How to make it work?

Comment: `imageUploadTask` is an [UploadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask) object, and works like a promise.  Use it to determine when an upload is complete.  After that, you can get its download url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the process of trial and error. I found a way which works for me.

```
for (const image of images) {
    const index = images.indexOf(image);

    await storage()
      .ref(`products/${dataUser.name}/${name}/${image.name}${index}`)
      .put(image);

    const url = await storage()
      .ref(`products/${dataUser.name}/${name}/${image.name}${index}`)
      .getDownloadURL();

    imageUrls.push(url);
  }
```

I can use this inside an async function and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a separate variable in which you will `.push(url)` push urls to.
see my example below:

```
    var imageUrls = []; // <======== set this as a separate variable and remove it from the next line
    
    images.map((image, index) => {
        const imageUploadTask = storage()
          .ref(`products/${dataUser.name}/${name}/${image.name}${index}`)
          .put(image);
    
        imageUploadTask.on(
          "state_changed",
          (snapshot) => {},
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          },
          () => {
            storage()
              .ref(`products/${dataUser.name}/${name}/${image.name}${index}`)
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then((url) => {
                console.log(url);
                imageUrls.push(url); // <============= add this line here
                return url; // <====== you can remove this
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          }
        );
      });
```